# Filter condition using filtered value

Tags: scala, functional-programming

I would like to filter collection, so distance between adjacent elements would be at least 5.

So `List(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 11, 20)` will become `List(1, 6, 11, 20)`.

Is it possible to achieve in one pass using filter? What would be scala-way?

Comment: The standard library `filter` HOF examines elements in isolation. Going to "extraordinary measures" by closing over mutable state outside the filter function in order to solve this problem would be ill-advised. The suggestions involving `fold`, assuming they satisfy the semantics you desire (which are not, to me, crystal clear) are vastly preferable. (If you said "between adjacent elements" instead of "between points," I'd say your request is sufficiently unambiguous and the suggested answers will work.)

Comment: Changed wording of question from "between points," to "between adjacent elements"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try with `foldLeft()`:

```
val input = List(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 11, 20)

input.tail.foldLeft(List(input.head))((out, cur) => 
  if(cur - out.head >= 5) cur :: out else out
).reverse
```

If it's not obvious:

1. Algorithm starts with first element (probably you need some edge cases handled) in the `output` collection
2. It iterates over all remaining elements from the `input`. If the difference between this element (`cur`) and first element of `input` is greater than or equal than `5`, prepend to `input`. Otherwise skip and proceed
3. `input` was built by prepending and examining `head` to get better performance. `.reverse` is needed in the end

This is basically how you would implement this in imperative way, but with more concise syntax.

Answer (score 7):

How about this one-liner:

```
scala> l.foldLeft(Vector(l.head)) { (acc, item) => if (item - acc.last >= 5) acc :+ item else acc }

res7: scala.collection.immutable.Vector[Int] = Vector(1, 6, 11, 20)
```